# Select files from directory order of there names

Tags: vb.net, sorting

I have 'N' number of files in a folder, the file names follows some common procedure(file0....fileN). the file names looks like:

```
file1.pdf
..
file7.pdf
..
file10.pdf
..
file15.pdf
..
fileN.pdf
```

Am collecting these files into a list of string using the following code:

```
  Dim Files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(folderBase + "\files", "*.pdf")
```

here what is the problem am facing is that am getting in the list in the following order:

```
file1.pdf
file10.pdf
..
file2.pdf
..
file15.pdf
..
fileN.pdf
```

Getting file10.pdf after file1.pdf. i want to get file names in the `sequential order(file1.pdf,file2.pdf...etc)`

i have tried this also but it will not solve my problem:

```
Dim Files As List(Of String) = Directory.GetFiles(folderBase + "\files", "*.pdf").OrderBy(Function(f) New FileInfo(f).Name).ToList()
```

Comment: This is not a solution but what about renaming your files like: File001.pdf, file010.pdf, file084.pdf and so on?

Comment: my files are not in that format. these are dynamically created files, numbers are not padded, so filenames doesnot contains 001 or002 etc

Comment: If files are created one after another, then you can read them based on the creation datetime.

Comment: One more point, while you are giving names to your file, then make an order like, File[DateTimeStamp] .. it will be easy to sort them.

Comment: Useful info here: http://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/

Comment: That is in order - lexicographical order.  the "1" in "File10" or "File199"  comes before "2" in "File2".   If you cant change the thing that creates them to use File### notation, you could go by the file creation date perhaps

Comment: thanks for new information`lexicographical `

Comment: @un-lucky - are you combining the different file extensions or are they separate?  I see *.pdf and *.enc filters.  I did post a 'natural order' solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use an `array` then sort function can be used

```
 Dim Files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(folderBase + "\files", "*.pdf")
 System.Array.Sort(Of String)(Files)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that uses sorted dictionary.  It assumes that the file names are letters followed by number(s).  This works by making the file names the same length and using that as the key for the sorted dictionary.

```
    'get the file name only
    Dim fnames As IEnumerable(Of String) = From f In Files
                                           Select IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)

    'get the longest file name
    Dim max As Integer = fnames.Max(Function(fs) fs.Length)
    'a palce for the results
    Dim sd As New SortedDictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim nums() As Char = "0123456789".ToCharArray
    'create dictionary entries.  
    For ix As Integer = 0 To fnames.Count - 1
        Dim fn As String = fnames(ix)
        Dim idx As Integer = fn.IndexOfAny(nums)
        If idx >= 0 Then fn = fn.Insert(idx, New String(" "c, max - fn.Length))
        sd.Add(fn, Files(ix))
    Next

    Dim l As List(Of String) = sd.Values.Select(Function(f) IO.Path.GetFileName(f)).ToList
```

When working with paths use the methods in IO.Path, e.g.

```
    Dim Files As String() = IO.Directory.GetFiles(IO.Path.Combine(folderBase, "files"), "*.pdf")
```

One other thing, use & for concatenation of strings not +.